# How to read a matrix in R with set size

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix, saved as a file (no extension) looking like this:

```
    Peter Westons NH 54 RTcoef level B matrix from L70 Covstats.
  2.61949322E+00  2.27966995E+00  1.68120147E+00  9.88238464E-01  8.38279026E-01
  7.41276375E-01  
  2.27966995E+00  2.31885465E+00  1.53558372E+00  4.87789344E-01  2.90254400E-01
  2.56963125E-01
  1.68120147E+00  1.53558372E+00  1.26129096E+00  8.18048022E-01  5.66120186E-01
  3.23866166E-01
  9.88238464E-01  4.87789344E-01  8.18048022E-01  1.38558423E+00  1.21272607E+00
  7.20283781E-01
  8.38279026E-01  2.90254400E-01  5.66120186E-01  1.21272607E+00  1.65314082E+00
  1.35926028E+00
  7.41276375E-01  2.56963125E-01  3.23866166E-01  7.20283781E-01  1.35926028E+00
  1.74777330E+00
```

How do I go about reading this in as a fixed 6*6 matrix, skipping the first header? I don't see any options for the amount of columns in read.matrix, I tried with the scan() -> matrix() option but I can't read in the file as the skip parameter in scan() doesn't seem to work.  I feel there must be a simple option to do this.

My original file is larger, and has 17 full rows of 5 elements and 1 row of 1 element in this structure, example of what needs to be in one row:

```
 [1] "  2.61949322E+00  2.27966995E+00  1.68120147E+00  9.88238464E-01  8.38279026E-01"
 [2] "  7.41276375E-01  5.23588785E-01  1.09559244E-01 -9.58430529E-02 -3.24544839E-02"
 [3] "  1.96694874E-02  3.39249911E-02  1.54438478E-02  2.38380549E-03  9.59475077E-03"
 [4] "  8.02748175E-03  1.63922615E-02  4.51778592E-04 -1.32080759E-02 -2.06313988E-02"
 [5] " -1.56037533E-02 -3.35496588E-03 -4.22450803E-03 -3.17468525E-03  3.23012615E-03"
 [6] " -8.68914773E-03 -5.94151619E-03  2.34059840E-04 -2.76737270E-03 -4.90334584E-03"
 [7] "  1.53812087E-04  5.69891977E-03  5.33816835E-03  3.32982333E-03 -2.62856968E-03"
 [8] " -5.15188677E-03 -4.47782553E-03 -5.49510247E-03 -3.71780229E-03  9.80192203E-04"
 [9] "  4.18101180E-03  5.47513662E-03  4.14679058E-03 -2.81461574E-03 -4.67580613E-03"
[10] "  3.41841523E-04  4.07771227E-03  7.06154094E-03  6.61650765E-03  5.97925136E-03"
[11] "  3.92987162E-03  1.72895946E-03 -3.47249017E-03  9.90977857E-03 -2.36066909E-31"
[12] " -8.62803933E-32 -1.32472387E-31 -1.02360189E-32 -5.11800943E-33 -4.16409844E-33"
[13] " -5.11800943E-33 -2.52126889E-32 -2.52126889E-32 -4.16409844E-33 -4.16409844E-33"
[14] " -5.11800943E-33 -5.11800943E-33 -4.16409844E-33 -2.52126889E-32 -2.52126889E-32"
[15] " -2.52126889E-32 -1.58614773E-33 -1.58614773E-33 -2.55900472E-33 -1.26063444E-32"
[16] " -7.93073863E-34 -1.04102461E-33 -3.19875590E-34 -3.19875590E-34 -3.19875590E-34"
[17] " -2.60256152E-34 -1.30128076E-34  0.00000000E+00  1.78501287E-02 -1.14423068E-11"
[18] "  3.00625863E-02"
```

So the full matrix should be 86*86.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: In your file the values for last column goes into next line as shown in the post here?

Comment: Yes, the single value on line 3 here is the 6th element of the first row. I want to read the first 6 elements as the first row, then start the next row at the 7th element of this file. Then this results in a 6*6 matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this option :

- Read the file with `readLines` removing the first line. (`[-1]`).
- Split values on whitespace and create 1 X 6 matrix from every combination of two rows.
- Combine them together in one matrix with `do.call(rbind, ..)`.

```
rows <- readLines('filename')[-1]

result <- do.call(rbind, 
               tapply(rows, ceiling(seq_along(rows)/2), function(x) 
                  strsplit(paste0(trimws(x), collapse = ' '), '\\s+')[[1]]))
```

Comment: Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)   Is the error I'm getting trying this sadly

Comment: Can you update your post with `dput(rows)` after running `rows <- readLines('filename')[-1]`

Comment: I have clarified it a bit. I tried changing to seq_along(rows/18), but the error is still there

Comment: Try the updated answer. If it doesn't work then it would be useful if you provide data in `dput` format. `dput(head(rows, 36))` would be enough.